# Upload tens of thousands of images via web interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a task where it needs to be possible to upload thousands of images in one go via a web interface.

The user selects the folder and the upload begins.

What is the best way to manage this from a UI point of view? Current UI uploaders seem inadequate.

How can I manage uploading a folder of images (recursively) to the server?

Additionally, how can error handling occur for failed uploads?

Edit:

This is for a citizen science project for a museum. The people (curators) mass uploading photos of collections (usually photos of fossils) need a simple way of uploading them to the server - FTP etc aren't suitable. A method through the web UI is needed.

Comment: File Transfer Protocol.

Comment: @TravisJ how would I use FTP from the UI?

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1496-PHP-Setup-FTP-connections-and-transfer-files.html may be a good PHP library to try...

Comment: You can look into the HTML5 File API and Blob along side XHR to achieve this. It is not an easy task, but is definitely possible as I have done this in the past.

Comment: Is FTP really the solution in 2015? What about sending a .zip file containing all the files you need over a regular form upload? What about having them dump things on Dropbox and then use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)? If you're feeling adventuresome, you can cobble together a client-side uploader using [NodeWebkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/tree/master) and give them an executable they can install.

Comment: Is there a mechanism through a web UI to do something similar to bittorrent sync? I'm gauging from the lack of responses this is a good area for some dev work to be done.

Comment: I found this service which seems to do the trick: http://cloudinary.com/